# Why am not able to find my username in the top user page

Tags: support, top-users, reputation-leagues

I tried to search for my user id in "Top User" page for the week and does not list me in the page. Is it not supposed to list me if I have at least 1 reputation?

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'll notice to the lower right of that page is this blurb:

> * users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues

As you've only gotten over 200 reputation *today*, you won't show up in the leagues until *tomorrow*. (Or, at least, when the process to refresh the league data runs.)